# Parameter expansion of variable containing control characters

Tags: bash, shell, parameter

I'm looking to replace the group separator control character, which is printed by the terminal as "^]" and has got octal code of: 035, with a space.

This can simply be done using tr, like so: `echo $line | tr '\035' ' '`.

However, I don't (can't) use an external command in my bash script, so am instead looking to use parameter expansion to replace the control characters with spaces.

What is the correct syntax to match the control character, the below options don't work:

```
${line//'\035'/' '}
${line//'\0035'/' '}
${line//\035/' '}
${line//$'\035'/' '}
```

Or is there another way to replace the character without using external commands such as tr and sed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that last one should work:

```
$ str=$(printf 'foo\035bar')
$ echo "${str//$'\035'/'X'}"
fooXbar
```

<sub>(though I added the double quotes around the expansion for the usual reasons, and in Bash 3.2, that makes the single quotes in the replacement end up as literals)</sub>

You could also just put the special character in a variable and use that in the middle part of the `${var/pattern/replacement}`:

```
$ special=$'\035'
$ str=$'foo\035bar'
$ echo "${str//$special/X}"
fooXbar
```

Comment: Thank you, that did actually work. Turns out I had placed the $ inside the single quotes rather than outside :')

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this can also be achieved using the POSIX-shell grammar. By using `$IFS` to split the string on the `\035` character and later concatenate its split arguments with space instead, it effectively performs the desired substitution.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

str=$(printf 'foo\035bar bar  baz   qux')

# Character \035 as Internal Field Separator
__oIFS=$IFS && IFS=$(printf '\035')

# shellcheck disable=SC2086 # Intended split on \035 into arguments
set -- $str && IFS=$__oIFS

# Expands arguments as space-delimited into $replStr
replStr=$*

printf '%s\n' "$replStr"
```

Comment: maybe `set -f` too, etc.